# A measurable function that does not admit pointwise approximation by step functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

A basic result in real analysis is that any measurable function is an a.e. limit of a step function sequence (yet a pointwise limit of a simple function sequence), but the statement does not hold when the “a.e.” is replaced with everywhere. My question is how to find a counterexample to the “everywhere” statement.

My attempt:
I’ve tried to use the fact that a step function is different from a simple one in that it is continuous on the complement of a zero-measure set, then maybe apply the Egorov’s thm. Considering this we are motivated to choose an everywhere discontinuous characteristic function of some “bad” measurable set. But then I got stuck, since once a.e. is involved, it seems hard to dispense with it (so as to arrive at an counter argument).

Please help, thx!

Comment: What's your definition of a step function?

Comment: Do you consider points/lines etc (e.g. singletons and $\{0\} \times [0,1]$) closed cubes?

Comment: @ClementYung Sorry I was a bit careless. It’s a linear combination  of characteristic functions of closed rectangles, and we allow the rectangles to degenerate (i.e. with empty interior).

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want. However a simple example is a function $=1$ for irrational points and $=0$ for rational points.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thank you, but I think Dirichlet function can be a limit of step functions. You just list rational points and construct disjoint small intervals to separate some of them at every finite stage.

Comment: @Juggler  I don't see the everywhere convergence.

Comment: @herbsteinberg You are right. I’m sorry. But we can just add a term corresponding to a single rational point every time and it follows that Dirichlet’s function is a limit of step functions. So is the difference between it and constant 1.

Comment: @Juggler  The rational points (in this construction) are one point step functions?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, and every finite stage we only have a finite and hence discrete subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to prove that there exists a Borel-measurable function which is not the everywhere-limit of any step function.

---

If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of real-valued functions on a set $X$, then its point of convergence is given by

$$E=\bigcap_{\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}}\bigcup_{N\geq1}\bigcap_{m,n\geq N}\{x\in X:|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon\}.$$

(Note that $E$ is precisely the set of all $x$ at which $(f_n(x))_{n\geq1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.)

Now, if $(f_n)$ is any sequence of step functions, then $\{x\in X:|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|<\varepsilon\}$ is a finite union of intervals. So, it is a $G_{\delta}$-set and hence belongs to the class $\mathbf{\Pi}_{2}^{0}$ in the [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy) on $\mathbb{R}$.

From this, we know that $E$ is an $G_{\delta\sigma\delta}$-set, and so, it lies in the class $\mathbf{\Pi}_{4}^{0}$. Since we know that [there exists a Borel set $B$ which is not in the class $\mathbf{\Pi}_{4}^{0}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330141/nontrivial-borel-sets), the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{B}$ is Borel-measurable but cannot be an everywhere-limit of any sequence of step functions.

Although I have little expertise in the descriptive set theory, it seems that no "natural" examples of Borel sets outside of $\mathbf{\Pi}_4^{0}$ is known in the literature. (See the comment in Section 23 of [*Kechris*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Classical_Descriptive_Set_Theory.html?id=WR3SBwAAQBAJ).) So, such set has to be artificially engineered. One such argument can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829706).

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have an answer. Note that step functions are all Borel-measurable, and a limit of Borel-measurable is also Borel-measurable. So take the characteristic function of a Lebesgue-measurable but non-Borel-measurable set and we have an example.